# Navigation Drawer Width Issue

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-designer

First of all, Thanks for giving Negative Votes in the first place. (i expect at least 10 negative votes to be honest by the honorable so-called "experts"(excluding those who believe even a simplest and smallest problem can cause a huge difference)).

So coming to my Question.

It's a very casual question that I am implementing a navigation drawer with a header image of 576x324(ratio as 16:9).

According to the Guidelines, the total width(in dp) of the drawer should be

for a device like 720x1280px screen and xhdpi

**width in dp = (720x160)/320 - 56(toolbar size)=> 304dp**

**height in dp = 304 * (9/16) = 171dp**

but the device like google nexus 4, 768x1280px with the same xhdpi

**width in dp = (768x160)/320 - 56(toolbar size)=> 328dp**

**height in dp = 304 * (9/16) = 184dp**

So, for the same xhdpi, I am getting two different widths and heights.

How can I manage this simple bug in android to make a common size in dimens.xml file?

Comment: rather than hardcoding the size. use it by %

Answer (score 0):

Get the Screen width *( int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels)*

Do the calculation by using this width.

Comment: so i need to do it programmatically?. well, i can do it. I just asked a casual question tbh..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calculating the width of drawer. What you can do is prepare the `dimens` file for different screen size. For example for `landscape and portrait`. For handling different layouts.

Store the width in the `dimens` and accordingly Android will fetch the suitable size.

```
<!-- Per the design guidelines, navigation drawers should be between 240dp and 320dp:
     https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html -->
<dimen name="navigation_drawer_width">240dp</dimen>
```

For more information on screen sizes: [Handling Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali)

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes i already have my layouts as sw,320dp,sw480dp,sw600dp,and sw720dp. but both devices have different resolution but same density. and calculating the width for different resolution with same density is confusing me

Comment: Rather than making common size. Give sizes according to the device width and you can use the dimens values for different layouts.